# Resize two iframes looses focus on mouse drag

Tags: jquery, iframe, resizable

I have two iframe horizontally (one above the other).
When I manually resize the top iframe the other resizes accordingly.

But when I drag the mouse downwards it does not work as well. It only works if I drag very slowly. Somehow it looses focus to the bottom iframe. I have made the bottom iframe smaller to see that it works great when I drag the mouse over it's DIV instead.

How to make it the same to drag up as well as down with the mouse?

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/ngjp0o1L/

**HEAD**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <style>
        #parent {
            position: absolute;
            height: 90%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 95%;
        }

        #div1 {
            position: relative;
            height: 50%;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #div2 {
            position: relative;
            height: 50%;
            background-color: green;
            z-index: 4;
        }
    </style>
```

**BODY**

```
<div id="parent">
       <div id="div1"> <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://www.example.com/" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe> </div>
       <div id="div2"> <iframe id="iframe2" src="http://www.example.com/" style="width:80%; height:100%;"></iframe> </div>
</div>

<script>

        $("#div1").resizable({
            start: function (event, ui) {
                ui.element.append($("<div/>", {
                    id: "iframe-barrier",
                    css: {
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        bottom: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        "z-index": 10
                    }
                }));
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $("#iframe-barrier", ui.element).remove();
            },
            resize: function (event, ui) {
                $("iframe", ui.element).width(ui.size.width).height(ui.size.height);
            }
        });
        $('#div1').resize(function () {
            $('#div2').height($("#parent").height() - $("#div1").height());
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Could you put this to jsfiddle so people experiment with it?

Comment: Hello Anton, I will try :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
The DIV that are appended only covers the top iframe/div.
I made it bigger to also cover the bottom iframe/div, and it does not loose focus anymore.